# How to select a value between a pattern from the right side in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table A with following data sample. I want to select the number `between` the last two `/`

[image: Data Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @text = '79011/67541/545415/5401dfd245/25405244';

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REPLACE(REVERSE(@text),LEFT(REVERSE(@text),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@text))),''),CHARINDEX('/',REPLACE(REVERSE(@text),LEFT(REVERSE(@text),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@text))),''))-1));
```

Check and then replace in your query `PHT` with `@text`.

**EDTI:**
More simple solution:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@text)
,CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@text)) + 1
,CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@text), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@text)) + 1) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@text)) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it -

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(SUBSTRING(PTH, 1, LEN(PTH) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(PTH))) 
        ,  CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(PTH))),'/','')  
FROM A
```

Comment: Are you sure that it works ok? I tried with sample string `'79011/67541/545415/5401245/25405244'` and it returns `55401245` which is wrong.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov - Yeah I just saw it. What am I doing incorrectly in my answer. Could you please edit it?

Comment: I can check tomorrow - I have to go AFK.

Comment: You are not removing the last element, @Reeya Oberoi.

Comment: You need something like: `SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@text)
,CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@text)) + 1
,CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@text), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@text)) + 1) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@text)) - 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
with x as 
(select charindex('/', reverse(pth)) as fst,
 charindex('/', reverse(pth), len(charindex('/', reverse(pth)))
+ charindex('/', reverse(pth))) as scnd
 from yourtable
)
select reverse(substring(reverse(pth), fst+1, scnd-fst-1)) from x
```

The fst and scnd meaning the first and second occurences of `/` from the end.

Answer (score 0):

If those items doesn't contain XML reserved chars one solution could be:

```
DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(8000)
SET     @Item = '11/22/33/44'

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Item VARCHAR(8000) NULL
)
INSERT  @MyTable 
VALUES  ('11/22/33/44'), ('11/22/33'), ('11/22'), ('11'), (' '), (''), (NULL)

SELECT  x.Item,
        CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(x.Item, '/', '</i><i>') + '</i>').value('(i[count(../i) - 1]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS NewItem
FROM    @MyTable x

/*
Item        NewItem
----------- -----------
11/22/33/44 33
11/22/33    22
11/22       11
11          NULL
            NULL
            NULL
NULL        NULL
*/
```

Comment: Otherwise (items could include XML reserved chars), `x.Item` must be replaced with `(SELECT x.Item AS '*' FOR XML PATH(''))`